# Solr: custom filed name conflicts with pseudo field names

Tags: search, solr, lucene, solr4

I have a schema with a custom field named `score`, which conflicts with Solr's built-in pseudo-field `score`. That is to say, when I issue query with `fl:*,score`, the pseudo-field `score` will override my custom `score` field.

P.S.: using a field alias like `fl=myscore:score,score` doesn't work.

How can I keep both field in query results?

Comment: Why not just change the name of the field?

Comment: You could also try giving an alias to the field name and see if it works (google: solr field alias), but I agree with the previous suggestion: why don't you just rename the field? Having conflicting names is error prone.

Comment: @femtoRgon Thanks for your useful comments. But currently our index is about 100GB and we'll prefer a workaround without re-indexing data.

Comment: did you get a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit old and I know this doesn't answer the question, but I came upon this post with a somehow related question that I happen to find a workaround for.

My question wasn't how to `fl` by a custom field named `score`, but how to sort by this field. For the same reason, if you sort by `score DESC` it uses Solr's pseudo-field `score`.

A workaround is to sort by `sum(score, 0)`.

Comment: I get `undefined field: \"score\"`